# Finding values that are different between two tables in MapInfo/MapBasic based on a unique ID

Tags: sql, mapinfo, mapbasic, where-clause

I am comparing 2 tables which are mostly the same but there have been some amendments, in effect comparing a new version to the old one and displaying all the records with changes in a selection table based on a unique ID.

I run into problems with the following SQL part of the script:

```sql
Select * From selectedTableNew, selectedTableOld 
Where (selectedColumnNew = selectedColumnOld) 
And (aColNew <> aColOld) 
Into AmendedRecords
```

I receive the error

> No join specified between *selectedTableNew* & *selectedTableOld*. Invalid join condition in WHERE clause."

Comment: Are some of the columns in your statement Alias variables and others not? I would expect you to only use Alias variables for all the column references in the SQL statement - or build it into a string and use Run Command to execute the SQL statement

Comment: AFAIK they are all Alias variables.

Comment: selectedColumnNew and selectedColumnOld have been Dim'ed as Alias variables and assigned a combination of a table name and column name using this structure: selectedTableNew & "." & selectedColumnNew ?

Comment: They are now :) - but now it seems that comparing the 2 tables it does not look at the same column, ie the Where statement part. I do a PRINT routine after each record and seems to compare random records with each other. But I think this might be due to the fact some of the values in the SelectedColumns are not unique.

Comment: I have tried formulating my suggestions into an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are using Alias variables in your SQL statement. You might want to change it to something along these lines:

```sql
Dim columnNew, selectedColumnNew, selectedTableNew As String
Dim columnOld, selectedColumnOld, selectedTableOld As String
Dim aSelectedColumnNew, aSelectedColumnOld, aColNew, aColOld As Alias

-- Here you assign the values to the string variables
-- I'm assuming you are using a dialog to ask the ser for input
selectedTableNew = "SomeTable"
selectedColumnNew = "SomeColumn"
columnNew = "SomeOtherColumn"
selectedTableOld = "SomeTable2"
selectedColumnOld = "SomeColumn2"
columnOld = "SomeOtherColumn2"

-- Now you link the table and columns to create a Alias
aSelectedColumnNew = selectedTableNew & "." & selectedColumnNew
aSelectedColumnOld = selectedTableOld & "." & selectedColumnOld
aColNew = selectedTableNew & "." & ColumnNew
aColOld = selectedTableOld & "." & ColumnOld

Select * From selectedTableNew, selectedTableOld 
   Where (aSelectedColumnNew = aSelectedColumnOld) 
   And (aColNew <> aColOld) 
   Into AmendedRecords
```

This should give you the records where the "selected" columns are identical and where the "other" column aren't.

Make sure that SelectedColumnNew/-Old are the ID's that should be the same in the two tables

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved with MapBasic like

> SELECT * FROM **TABLE_1** WHERE NOT *table_1_column* IN (
>          SELECT *table_2_column* FROM **TABLE_2**
>      ) INTO Selection

or as a code

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE NOT table_1_column IN (
    SELECT table_2_column FROM TABLE_2
) INTO Selection

BROWSE * FROM Selection
```

or with SQL select

[image]

Comment: This is not what I'm after unfortunately as this SQL simply looks for new records in 1 column, instead of going through every column looking for changes in records between the 2 tables.